# Getting cross domain errors with getJSON even when specifying callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to use the following to get metadata from Worldcat about some books:

`$.getJSON( " http://xisbn.worldcat.org/webservices/xid/isbn/" + $isbn[1] + "?method=getMetadata&format=json&callback=mymethod&fl=*");`

Where $isbn[1] is a ten or thirteen digit number (0123456789 works).

I can put http://xisbn.worldcat.org/webservices/xid/isbn/0123456789?method=getMetadata&format=json&callback=mymethod&fl=* and I get the results I need, but I'm not crossing domains to do that.

The console is reporting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xisbn.worldcat.org/webservices/xid/isbn/0123456789?method=getMetadata&format=json&callback=mymethod&fl=*. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

I am doing all this on jsfiddle. Thinking maybe that could be the problem I tried locally, but no difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are getting a cors error, you aren't making a jsonp request. you should not be specifying a method yourself, instead you should be using `??` for the callback as specified in the documentation.

Comment: Ok, I had this later, but this isn't enough / doesn't work?

`mymethod = function(data){
  alert(data.foo);
};`

Comment: @KevinB, true if the callback variable is there it should. However like you said it needs to be `?`

Comment: @pr3sidentspence please provide a code sample where you attempted to use `callback=??`. It works for me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dkmLchoL/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pr3sidentspence/y5rjhqnk/10/

Comment: You still have `callback=mymethod` instead of `callback=??`. That's not how jQuery getJSON works. You have to let jQuery create the function that is to be called.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what callback=?? means. And I just realized I read your first comment backwards.

Comment: [See A.Wolff's jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkmLchoL/).

Comment: this is your fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5rjhqnk/11/

Comment: Ok, I've got it now, thanks everyone.

Comment: Am I too new to upvote or mark as answer? I don't see any UI for that.

Comment: Comments can't be marked as an answer, Someone would actually have to type out an answer, or you can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't following the API documentation properly and put the success handler's name in the URL, rather than sending it as the data parameter.

I had:

```
 $.getJSON( "http://example.com?method=getMetadata&format=json&callback=mymethod&fl=*");
```

But it should have been:

```
$.getJSON( "http:/example.com?method=getMetadata&format=json&fl=*&callback=?", mymethod);
```